# Django forms: "This field is required" when file POSTed to file field

Tags: django, forms

I for some reason am unable to get a file to into my filefield in my ModelForm. The file is submitted and the file name is in the corresponding POST request, however the `form.is_valid()` fails as it states `{'the_file': [u'This field is required.']}`

I have written a ModelForm for a model with a file field in and a foreign key to another model, thus:

```
class AccountFile(models.Model):
the_file = models.FileField(upload_to='{}/%Y/%m/%d/'.format(
    settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
))
account = models.ForeignKey(
    Account,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    related_name='account_files'
```

I've then generated a form to upload a file, thus:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.AccountFile
    fields = ['the_file' ]


def clean_file(self):
    file = self.cleaned_data.get("the_file", False)
    filetype = magic.from_buffer(file.read())
    if not "pdf" in filetype:
        raise forms.ValidationError("File is not pdf.")
    return file
```

Putting in some very basic validation (which will be extended!) when I can get at least one thing to work.

The form is processed like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        return redirect(
            'account_url',
            acc_manager_pk=acc_manager.pk,
            account_pk=account.pk,
            )
else:
    form = forms.UploadFileForm()
```

This is on Django 1.7

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Make sure that your form has the `enctype` set, e.g.:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that **request.FILES** will only contain data if the request method was **POST** and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"**. Otherwise, **request.FILES** will be empty.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've read that page about 10 times and saw that on the first read but then missed it on every other read to find out what I had missed. On to the next error!

Comment: Make sure you notice the request.FILES above ... this needs to be used when initializing your form in a POST request (add_document_form = AddDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES). I always forget this part.