# Django forms: “This field is required” when file POSTed to file field WITH enctype

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I fail to upload a file and get "This field is required." Up until now it's the same as the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891306/django-forms-this-field-is-required-when-file-posted-to-file-field). However, I **am** using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` like suggested in that issue.

The model:

```
class ContentSheet(models.Model):
    content_sheet_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content_sheet_file = models.FileField()
```

The form:

```
class ContentSheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content_sheet_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_sheet_name.widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': 'autofocus', 'placeholder': 'Content Sheet Name'})
    content_sheet_file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = ContentSheet
        exclude = tuple()
```

The view:

```
def add_user_sentence(request):
    statistics_context = get_statistics()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContentSheetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new sentence to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)
             print "form.content_sheet_file", form.content_sheet_file
             ...
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = ContentSheetForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    context = {'user_sentence_form': form}
    return render(request, 'lf_classifier/insert_text.html', context)
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="user_sentence_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/lf_classifier/send_text/">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for field in user_sentence_form.visible_fields %}
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}

                <input type="submit" data-icon="action" data-iconpos="right" name="submit" data-inline="true" value="upload" />
            </form>
```

Comment: show your ContentSheet model

Comment: Are there other fields in `ContentSheet` or is it just `content_sheet_name` and `content_sheet_file`? On which field do you get the error? Is there any value in it?

Comment: you need to mention a path in your model like `FileField(upload_to='directory_name/')`

Comment: @Exprator, I added upload_to='uploads/' and it still doesn't work and gives the same message

Comment: Where is your view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - added the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `data-ajax="false"` resolved my issue. The fixed HTML:

```
<form id="user_sentence_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false"  action="/lf_classifier/send_text/">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% for field in user_sentence_form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" data-icon="action" data-iconpos="right" name="submit" data-inline="true" value="upload" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't passed the file data to the form.

```
form = ContentSheetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Upvoted and updating your fix in the question - but am still getting the same error :(