# Django Upload Folder is always Empty (This field is required issue)

Tags: django, file-upload, directory-upload

I would like to upload a folder to my application but on the server side the **request.FILES** collection is always empty.

Also **form.is_valid** evaluates to false

The solution for this problem seems to be to add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** but I have already added it an it doesn't work.
As described here [SO TOPIC ABOUT THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891306/django-forms-this-field-is-required-when-file-posted-to-file-field)

Inside the browser I also get "This field is required" after pressing submit and yes I have choosen a directory.

Here my relevant code

*model.py*

```
# Create your models here.
class Datasets(models.Model):

    dataset_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    share_with = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    datafiles = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

*form.py*

```
class UploadDatasetForm(forms.Form):

    dataset_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    description = forms.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    share_with = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=tuple(UserProfile.objects.values_list('id', 'full_name')),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
    datafiles = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
        attrs={
            'multiple': True,
            'webkitdirectory': True,
            'directory': True,
        }))
```

*the template*

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Register Here</h2>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
```

*view.py*

```
@login_required
def upload_dataset(request):
    print(request.user)
    form = UploadDatasetForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('Receiving a post request')
        form = UploadDatasetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("The form is valid")
            print(form.cleaned_data)

            dataset_name = form.cleaned_data['dataset_name']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            datafiles = form.cleaned_data['datafiles']
            share_with = form.cleaned_data['share_with']
            users_to_share_with = set()

            print(datafiles)

            instance = Datasets.objects.create(
                uploaded_by=request.user,
                dataset_name=dataset_name,
                description=description,
                datafiles = datafiles,
                upvotes=0,
                downvotes=0,
            )

            for i in share_with:
                instance.share_with.add(i)

            return redirect("public:data")
            print("The Dataset has been uploaded")

    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "upload_dataset.html", context)
    {% endblock %}
```

I receive the message Receiving a post request but it will not go inside the **form.is_valid**

The output after pressing the submit button is

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 25, 2021 - 11:42:53
Django version 3.2.3, using settings 'platform_oliveoils.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:40/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Max
Receiving a post request
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

Comment: Your model has `datafiles = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)` which expects a single file. That doesn’t match up with trying to handle multiple files. I would try to get it working with a single file, then try to get multiple files working, then finally try to get the directory option to work.

Comment: Okay I have figured it out how to do it for multiple files but I am still not able to do it for a directory. How can I get the subdirectory folder names for example and pass the name through to the models.py where I have the upload_to attribute

Comment: I'm not familiar with `directory` or `webkitdirectory` so I can't help with that. Note the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) warn against using it because it's non standard.